# Fix corrupted Xbox USB

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

I was playing Batman on my Xbox last night. This morning I turned on my Xbox and noticed that my profile wasn't there. I went then into "System Tools and Storage" and it says that USB is not formatted for the Xbox. If I plug it into a PC it says that it is not formatted too.

I didn't have a split memory for PC and Xbox. Does anyone know to how fix it?

Comment: USB... hard drive?

Comment: @JeffMercado probaly USB Flash drive. You are limited to 16GB on one for Xbox 360 stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your profile is saved in the cloud, so if you want to recover it follow the steps in this page: http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live/how-to/xbox-live-account-management/gamer-profile#recover

As for the saved games and other data, if the USB memory is corrupted you could try the answers to this SuperUser question: https://superuser.com/questions/51984/how-do-i-recover-files-from-an-usb-flash-drive. As CyberSkull points out, you shouldn't have problems reading the files because it uses FAT32.

Comment: The filesystem is FAT32 with 1GB disk image files that host the Xbox 360 data. If you can recover the images you stand a good chance of being able to get your saves back. Dec 6th 2011 when the Metro Dashboard update goes live, use the cloud save feature to back up your games to that as well.

Comment: @HenryHey Thanks for the reply. I tried different data recovery programs to get the files back with no real prospect. The filesystem comes up as RAW. I ended up buying a new usb and downloading my profile to that usb. I then downloaded Modio and found a saved game that was very close to what i was up to. It was the best solution i could find.

Comment: @CyberSkull I knew about the cloud service that was meant to be coming this year and was kicking myself from having my usb die now...Lost 6 years of gaming :-(

Comment: @TimothyRuhle I accidentally hit "delete all" once and made a mad dash to hit the power button on my 360. I lost part of my games (especially a few RPGs I forgot to backup) and in my "conversations" with MS support I learned just how badly designed the filesystem is. The Xbox 360 doesn't use [journaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system), a basic feature of filesystems for nearly 10 years now. They also said they didn't have any filesystem tools for anything like file recovery or drive repair. That news really upset me.